# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'rollno' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I went through a number of links regarding this exception. I don't know whether the action class has a problem or the jsp.

My DAO is:

```
         {
            ReleaseData releaseData = new ReleaseData();
            releaseData.setRollno(resultSet.getInt("rollno"));
            releaseData.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            releaseData.setAge(resultSet.getInt("age"));
            myDataList.add(releaseData);
            System.out.println("the List has---"+myDataList);
        }
```

And my Servlet is:

```
            public class DisplayServlet extends HttpServlet
          {
                public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    List<ReleaseData> myDataList = new ReleaseDataDAO().getReleaseData();
    request.setAttribute("myDataList", myDataList);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/showData.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

And here is my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="$(myDataList)" var="data">
             <tr>
               <td>${data.rollno}</td>
                 <td>${data.name}</td>
                <td>${data.age}</td>

              </tr>
             </c:forEach>
```

Comment: `ReleaseData` is public class with public valid accessor for rollno ?

Comment: using $(myDataList) instead of ${myDataList}

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm I've just noticed, you are using `$()` instead of `${}`, jsp is not jQuery :P this `$(myDataList)` is not being interpreted as an EL expression and becoming a String, do this instead: `${myDataList}`

Also:

You need to create the getter and setter methods, in the code you provided I could see a set method to rollno but no get method, also they must be public

```
public class ReleaseData{
    private int rollno = 0;
    private String name = "";
    private int age = 0;

    public int getRollno(){ return rollno; }
    public void setRollno(int rollno){ this.rollno = rollno; }

    public int getAge(){ return age; }
    public void setAge(int age){ this.age= age; }

    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public void setName(String name ){ this.name = name; }

}
```

Also, it's always nice to escape any data that can be entered by a human.

```
<c:forEach items="${myDataList}" var="data">
 <tr>
   <td><c:out value="${data.rollno}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${data.name}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${data.age}" /></td>

  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks mate..it wrkd...btw setters nd getter were provided..its jus i didnt display ovr here..

Comment: You are welcome. Could you give me rate my answer so I can get reputation score in trade? Thank you :P